# Dynamically query a subset of columns in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Assume only two columns(name and id) are needed from a table. I would code something like below:

```
session.query(User.id, User.name).all()
```

But if the column names are dynamic,

```
def get_data(table, columns):
    return session.query(*(getattr(table, column) for column in columns)).all()
```

But the above one looks ugly. Is there a better recommended way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get use of [select()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

columns = ['id', 'name']
print(session.query(select(from_obj=User, columns=columns)).all())
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. it works. Is this equivalent to `query(User.id, User.name)` or are there any differences?

Comment: add `from sqlalchemy.sql import select`

Comment: Not sure why I receive `Textual column expression 'name' should be explicitly declared with text('name'), or use column('name') for more specificity"`

Comment: If you get the Textual column expression error, you can map column() to each array element, like so:

1) Import sqlalchemy.sql.column `from sqlalchemy.sql import column` 2) map column() to each array element
`specific_cols = list( map(lambda x: column(x), columns) )`

Now it should work without any error:
`session.query(select(from_obj=User, columns=specific_cols)).all()`

Comment: I don't think this answer works any more. The OP's solution is the correct solution according to latest update from SQLAlchemy:
`Changed in version 1.4: The select() construct now accepts column arguments positionally, as select(*args). The previous style of select() accepting a list of column elements is now deprecated. See select(), case() now accept positional expressions.` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql

Comment: So... how can this be done in 2023?

Comment: in 2023 you can use 
`columns = ["id", "name"]`, then
`cols = [getattr(MyModel, col) for col in columns]`, then
`query = select(*cols)`