# Call table values dynamically with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a table named "info_test" mapped like this:

```
class db_info_test(BASE):

__tablename__ = "info_test"

id              = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name            = Column(String)
project         = Column(String)
manufacturer    = Column(String)
```

If I want to get the names of all items from that table I would do something like this:

```
import db_info_test     
for row in self.session.query(db_info_test):
    print(row.name)
```

which would print:

```
name_of_item_A
name_of_item_B
...
```

Now I want to create a very generall function that prints the value of a key, where the key is given by an argument of that function. Something like this:

```
def get_value(self, table, key):
    for row in self.session.query(table):
        print(row.key)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251724/how-to-give-column-name-dynamically-from-string-variable-in-sql-alchemy-filter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102412/dynamically-query-a-subset-of-columns-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) is used for getting attributes based on variables. As an addition, you don't need to query the whole model object and all its attributes, if all you want is just one:

```
def get_value(self, table, key):
    # Note the comma after value. It unpacks the 1-tuples.
    for value, in self.session.query(getattr(table, key)):
        print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks man! Never heard of getattr() before. This is very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Will

```
print(dict(row)[key])
```

do the job for you?